# What port is this, labeled with "I/F"?

Tags: port

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: some context would help - what is the device in question?

Comment: Obvously, the "I/F" stands for "Inter Face".  (Yeah, would help to know the brand and age of the device... and what kind of device it is, if not a laptop.)

Comment: It is impossible to tell what this port is if you don't tell us what device this port is on. Is this on a laptop? A keyboard? A modem? If you don't even know what sort of device this is, try editing your post to add a picture of the whole device. Then we can stop guessing and try to come up with a reasonable hypothesis for what this port is for. I've seen this connector used for everything from power connectors, to serial ports to s-video, so we really are taking shots in the dark.

Answer (score 7):

Well, its seems to be a standard 8 pin mini din port, [apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector#8-pin) - if its a sun or apple device, it might be a serial port - it looks identical to the passthrough port on my sun model 5c keyboard .

If it had 7 pins, i'd guess it was a [firewire port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector#7-pin_2), since that looks like an old macbook, but the shape is wrong.

Comment: Used for mice and keyboards.

Comment: Well, i can't tell. All i can say for certain is, its *some* sort of mini din port, and its not a sun box, so it can't be a sun serial port. I'm not even sure if its a computer - too fat for a laptop, and no obvious markings to tell what it is. Its almost like one of bunny huang's ware of the week!

Comment: Just saying that that is what I have seen them used for.

Comment: That was my first thoughts.  Sure looks like the old Mac "serial" ports.

Comment: ya. *what* that connector itself is certain. I *really* cannot say without seeing the device. I'm trying to remember if i've seen it used for midi on professional devices. I also think some maudio internal sound cards use it as a breakout box, but this isn't one and...

Comment: An 8 pin mini din is a *standard* connector, it could be used for almost *anything*. Without he context of what the questioners device actually is we are just thrashing around blindly in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Been searching around, and from I've gathered, it appears to be some sort of ethernet port. Though it is nowhere mentioned explicitly

Sources: [gigabit ethernet port](http://reviews.cnet.com/networking-and-wi-fi/gigabti-enet-port-i/4505-3243_7-415702.html?tag=subnav), [P113S LF A 10/100 Base-TX / 100 Base-FX Converter](http://www.icplus.com.tw/pp-IP113S.html) and [some PDF](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=smii%20i/f&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http://www.mentor.com/products/ip/ethernet/10_100_mbps/upload/serial-media-independent-interface-smii-for-pe-macmii-pe-mcxmac-8f4c7958-a3ef-11ba-f6c6-053f83fc3511&ei=p_rhTqjUJIWk-gb9gtzJBQ&usg=AFQjCNEzMTRHNrEysv8rym8RT2CJVndN6A&sig2=MT5MacXuOyfSS5v-RCKIjw&cad=rja)

But then in another source, it is a general term for input devices ([Link](http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%22i/f%20port%22&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CE4QFjAF&url=http://www.samsungpresenter.com/info/pst_total_general.pdf&ei=aPrhTqjlLoGf-waG2YjYBQ&usg=AFQjCNHZ3-HZgsdAMbKoI3reh3RxlX04gA&sig2=mZ-txNpp_Ms-fJe15gO9kg&cad=rja) PDF)

Comment: hm. I have seen one of the latter before - fiber optic ethernet would *not* use pins.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of video cards have a port like this that is for attaching a Composite/Component breakout box dongle. This is a picture of one of the connector, but I have one at home on a 9800 GTX+ that has a different pin layout.  This image is from 2004, so the pin layout has probably changed since then.

[image]

Comment: Thats one of the things wikipedia mentioned. darned non standard ports ><